# Путаница с разбиением модулей по папкам

Tags: angular, модули

В папке home есть компонент TestComponent, в котором я пытаюсь вызвать компонент profileComponent, с папки shared. Как мне это правильно сделать, если в этих папках есть свои модули компонент?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-separated-modules-howto

Comment: у вас там же все пути перепутаны. Обращение к home.component которого нет, потом test.component ищет в другой папке. В чем вопрос то ? Как поменять пути ?

Comment: Вот поправил просто пути 

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-separated-modules-howto-1e4vqm

Comment: Спасибо! Да, это оно) @zalex, напишите, пожалуйста, это как ответ на вопрос, я отмечу галочкой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уж раз ответил. Вся проблема была попросту в не правильном указании путей к компонентам. Могу предположить что используя IDE у вас таких сложностей  не будет возникать.